# Custom Listview Rows causing ListView to struggle after a few Entries

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I wrote a software for handling Pizza Payments as a school project. For this I create a custom row as a Anchorpane. After loading a few Entries from a MySQL DB, the ListView for showing the possible Pizzas to choose is struggling (showing white space above and under the entries, where the other Entries should be displayed but aren't).

If you want to see the main Pane FXML click [here](https://gist.github.com/665abe02b26bd691e33893e663e7bb8a), if you want to see the Custom ListCell Anchorpane just click [here](https://gist.github.com/b1370bbf5de64c4bac48bc3148642d07).

To see the error visually just click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt8aj.jpg)

Because I have no idea how this custom cells are rendered in detail I have no idea where the error is, so I tried nothing to fix it.

```
//the adding a new Pizza Row method in the WindowController Class for the main window
 private void addPizzaRow(Pizza pizza) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File(WindowController.ROW_FXML).toURI().toURL());

            pizzenContr = new RowPizzasController();
            loader.setController(pizzenContr);

            Pane rootPane = loader.load();

            // initialize tab controller
            pizzenContr.init(pizza);

            this.pizzenListview.getItems().add(rootPane);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

```
//the called init() method
public void init(Pizza pizza) {
        pizzaImageview.setImage(new Image("Classdependencies/Window/PizzaListViewImg.png"));

        //set title and image (icon)
        this.pizzaLabel.setText(pizza.getName());
        this.kleinButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });
```

After five or 6 Entries white space above and under the entries is showing, where the other Entries should be displayed but aren't.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also how big is the image? I strongly recommend using custom `ListCell`s and reusing the same `Image` instead of loading the same image into memory once for every single item.

Comment: @fabian Should I provide the fxml files or what do you need? Not so sure about that, the visual error is attached

Comment: As fabian said, you really need to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. The code you posted so far does not even include the custom `ListCell` implementation causing the issue you're asking for help with...

Comment: @Zephyr I included the ListCell File as a link and I will describe more detail when the error shows up.

Comment: This is kind of working as expected, the issue is that the number of cells is being calculated incorrectly based on prefHeight.  This means that even though the total height is large, the cells are only filling up about 75% of the ListView.  The list view is taking cells from the top and re-using them on the bottom, as you would expect.  There is a post somewhere that fixes this, I sadly just can't find it.  But try playing around with the prefHeight values of the list view.

Comment: The fix was to set height to auto in scene builder so no it works, looks like some of Scenebuilder bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error had something todo with absolute height I gave the cells Panes after I set this to default in Scenebuilder it worked fine again.